# Xtk : Can't display label map

Tags: javascript, webgl, xtk, medical

I slightly changed demo #11 to load my images instead of the demo's.

I can load my MRI image just fine, see [Demo](http://sd-33294.dedibox.fr/~joel/private/mri22/demo.html). It also works if I load my label map as the main volume.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // create and initialize a 3D renderer
    var r = new X.renderer3D();
    r.init();

    // create a X.volume
    var volume = new X.volume();

    // Attach the single-file dicom in .NRRD format
    // this works with gzip/gz/raw encoded NRRD files but XTK also supports other
    // formats like MGH/MGZ
    volume.file = '1123_N3.nii.gz';

    // we also attach a label map to show segmentations on a slice-by-slice base
    // volume.labelmap.file = '1123_seg.nii.gz';

    // add the volume
    r.add(volume);

    // the onShowtime method gets executed after all files were fully loaded and just before the first rendering attempt
    r.onShowtime = function() {
        //
        // The GUI panel
        //
        // (we need to create this during onShowtime(..) since we do not know the
        // volume dimensions before the loading was completed)
        var gui = new dat.GUI();

        // the following configures the gui for interacting with the X.volume
        var volumegui = gui.addFolder('Volume');

        // now we can configure controllers which switch between slicing and volume rendering
        var vrController = volumegui.add(volume, 'volumeRendering');

        // configure the volume rendering opacity
        var opacityController = volumegui.add(volume, 'opacity', 0, 1).listen();

        // and the threshold in the min..max range
        var lowerThresholdController = volumegui.add(volume, 'lowerThreshold', volume.min, volume.max);
        var upperThresholdController = volumegui.add(volume, 'upperThreshold', volume.min, volume.max);

        // the indexX,Y,Z are the currently displayed slice indices in the range [0 - (dimensions-1)]
        var sliceXController = volumegui.add(volume, 'indexX', 0, volume.range[0] - 1);
        var sliceYController = volumegui.add(volume, 'indexY', 0, volume.range[1] - 1);
        var sliceZController = volumegui.add(volume, 'indexZ', 0, volume.range[2] - 1);
        volumegui.open();

        // and this configures the gui for interacting with the label map overlay
        var labelmapgui = gui.addFolder('Label Map');
        var labelMapVisibleController = labelmapgui.add(volume.labelmap, 'visible');
        var labelMapOpacityController = labelmapgui.add(volume.labelmap, 'opacity', 0, 1);
        labelmapgui.open();

    };

    // adjust the camera position a little bit, just for visualization purposes
    r.camera.position = [120, 80, 160];

    // showtime! this triggers the loading of the volume and executes r.onShowtime() once done
    r.render();
};
```

However if I add the label map to my volume, `volume.labelmap.file = '1123_seg.nii.gz';`, the loading fails and the volume never shows, see [Broken Demo](http://sd-33294.dedibox.fr/~joel/private/mri22/demo2.html). The only error in the console is the following:

> TypeError: b.e.c[0].c[Math.floor(...)] is undefined

Any idea as to what might be wrong? How am I supposed to debug such errors?

Comment: I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'C' of undefined` in the console.

Comment: The links you have given don't work for me (pages never load)

Comment: @Fresh : demo.html works, but you need to be patient because you're downloading a 3D volume from my server. On my computer it loads in about ten seconds, but if you live far away I suppose it can take longer.

Comment: I get the same as @ReCaptcha

Comment: Have you tested this with any other files? I'm playing around with this stuff as well at the moment, and some files just don't seem to load while others load perfectly fine. Haven't figured out a pattern unfortunately...

Comment: @Fresh what browser do you use? I've only tested with firefox.

Comment: @DavidBasalla : can you confirm that demo.html works for you? Let me know if you find anything useful!

Comment: @static_rtti I've only tried loading "Broken Demo" using Chrome.

Comment: yup, demo.html works fine for me, I'm on Ubuntu and Firefox

Comment: hmm... I've come across the same problem now. I'm basing my tests on Xtk Lesson 13. When I use the same files as in the tutorial, everything loads fine. However when I specify my own custom file as volume.file but still use the same label map and color table as from the tutorial, I get the same error (TypeError: b.e.c[0].c[Math.floor(...)] is undefined). So maybe it has something to do with a mismatch between volume.file and volume.labelmap.file?

Comment: @DavidBasalla : the mismatch theory makes sense, but my files are supposed to match...

Comment: Mmm yeah, unfortunately I'm only guessing at this point. I'm actually going to work on this (ie using custom files and label maps) over the next couple of weeks, so will let you know if I find anything else

Comment: @DavidBasalla : Thanks! Any additional info would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript libraries like this are usually minified for production ready versions. It's nearly impossible to debug minified javascript code, but you can see one of the method names in the callstack is .parse, which indicates right away that it's having an issue parsing your labelmap file.

Most javascript libraries will also include a -debug version that is not minified. I can't seem to find one for xtk, but here's the process for creating a debug version for yourself:

1. Clone the latest xtk project:

   git clone https://github.com/xtk/X.git
2. Update google closure (the source is not included):

   cd X/lib/
   git clone https://github.com/google/closure-library
   mv closure-library google-closure-library
3. I created a demo.html file in the X directory, but you can probably put it anywhere and set it up like:

   `<script src="lib/google-closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>`
   `<script src="xtk-deps.js"></script>`
   `<script>
       goog.require("X");
       goog.require("X.renderer3D");
    </script>`
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>`

Now you can debug, and you should see your error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_texture' of undefined parser.js:1205
X.parser.reslice parser.js:1205
X.parserNII.parse parserNII.js:258
(anonymous function)
```

From here you should be able to hunt down your issue.  Looks like a texture is missing.